# Android ListView - Some element has wrong position

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I use AsyncTask for parsing JSON and loading in ListView(text, images and other), but some elements after loading are has wrong position or are repeated. How to fix it?

For example:

1

2

2

3

4

4

Code AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                // instantiate our json parser
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

                // get the array of users
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("data");


                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String nickname = c.getString("nickname");
                    products.add(new Product(nickname));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) { SetAdapter(); }
    }
```

And i use simple BaseAdapter, code:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  Context ctx;
  LayoutInflater lInflater;
  ArrayList<Product> objects;
  String name, rating, desc, date;
  long date_time;
  Integer rate;
  ImageView imageID;
  TextView textDesc;

  BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }


  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
  }


  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
  }


  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }


  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);
    textDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

    if (p.username.contains("null"))
    {
        name = "Автор: Неизвестен";
    }
    else
    {
       name = "Автор: " + p.username;
    }

    if(!p.description.contains("null"))
    {
        desc = p.description.replaceAll("<br />", "");
        desc = desc.replaceAll("&quot;", "");
    }

    date_time = Long.parseLong(p.created_at);
    Date dates = new Date(date_time*1000L);
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM в HH:mm");
    time.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+4"));
    date = time.format(dates);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating)).setText(p.rating);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(desc);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(date);

    return view;
  }

  Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
  }

}
```

Comment: You have the two getitem function you may delete the one

Comment: why you use two methods for getItem use only one method for taking position of the listview.

Comment: I deleted, but it does not solve my problem; (